# how to convert an int/value into a curreny/price?

Tags: php, sql, drupal

im using drupal,

I have a field, where users specify a price.

Ive printed the price field in my tpl.

```
<?php print $node->my_form['amt'] ?>
```

but the price comes out like 0.050, How do I get this to display £0.50?

Comment: I think you meant 0.050 -> £0.05, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`money_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) or see [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) or the `printf` variant:

```
<?php printf('£%01.2f', $node->my_form['amt']) ?>

Output: £0.05
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/W1ARoTQo)

Comment: Tell your browser to display the website in the UTF-8 encoding, see http://www.w3.org/International/getting-started/characters - Or use the `&pound;` HTML entity instead.

Answer (score 1):

See [`money_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check the details here http://www.drupalcommerce.org/faq/currency-format and make sure you have a currency formatter configured/chosen.

Depending also on how you're geting your prices, you might want to see this issue http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/633 with the solution.